# Linux File and Process Level I/O performance metrics

Tags: linux, performance, file, process, io

Has anyone come up with a solution that allows the I/O performance metrics (IOPs, MBps) to be reported at the process and/or file level?  I'm not sure if Linux keeps this info available, but wanted to reach out see what others are doing.

My use cases are:

1) I know that a particular file system and/or device is running hot, but I want to know if it's a particular file that's being accessed or multiple.  Potentially the filesystem itself exposes this information.  Assume I'm using the typical Linux file systems.

2) I want to know which processes are contributing to the load.  Specifically how can I report throughput (MBps), IOPs, response times at the process level?  I know that the app could be instrumented to work this stuff out, however, i'm more interested in understanding if the OS exposes this level of data.

Comment: for 2) use your processes to log whatever info you need, like file access and timestamp

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get the list of of all open files on some device (for example, sda1) with `lsof /dev/sda1`. But it's unlikely to get throughput information on file level (at least I don't know how).
2. You can get throughput on process level with `iotop`. I don't know any convenient way to get IOPS, but you can find it periodically reading `/proc/[number]/io`.